# SQL query to from these two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select

I have these two tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
    FirstName varchar(50),
    LastName varchar(50),
    Age int,
    City varchar(50)
)

CREATE TABLE pets
(
    Id int NOT NULL 
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customer(Id), 
    animal varchar(50),
    color varchar(50),
    Age int
)
```

I want to get the full names of customers who have an orange cat but it should not give multiple results even for customers who have multiple orange cats.

Comment: Tag spam doesn't help us help you; tag the RDBMS you are using and *only* that RDBMS. I have removed all the conflicting tags

Comment: Hint - learn about the [EXISTS()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) operator. E.g., `select ... from Customer where EXISTS (...)`

Comment: That's a specification. What's the question?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make your question much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `exists` operator:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   customer c
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   pets p
               WHERE  p.animal = 'cat' AND
                      p.color = 'orange' AND
                      p.id = c.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Group By or Distinct to get unique results

```
SELECT 
    FirstName,
    LastName
FROM 
    Customer
LEFT JOIN PETS on CUSTOMER.ID = PETS.ID 
WHERE PETS.COLOR = 'Orange'
and PET.ANIMAL = 'Cat'
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    FirstName,
    LastName
FROM 
    Customer
LEFT JOIN PETS on CUSTOMER.ID = PETS.ID 
WHERE PETS.COLOR = 'Orange'
and PET.ANIMAL = 'Cat'
```

Comment: Why `LEFT JOIN` when it's impossible for the `WHERE` to be TRUE when no row is found?

Comment: My bad, you're right, the left join isn't optimal here

Comment: Thnaks for thequery. The first one works but is there a way to have the list in the order as it is in Customer table?

Comment: You can add the Id to the Select and Group by and Sort by it

Answer (score 0):

We can use **DISTINCT** Keyword to get unique First and LastNames

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.FirstName ,C.LastName 
    FROM dbo.Customer C
    INNER JOIN dbo.Pets P ON C.ID = P.ID
    WHERE P.color = 'Orange'
        AND P.animal = 'Cat'
```